# Sign up for WordPress without username but with user id Unique

Tags: php, wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I have a simple registration form WordPress.
I was able to cancel the Username field,
Then what happens now - the user's email is the username.
I want to have no username, just id user Unique.

If it's not possible so maybe to send the same email but add a number later automatically, like:

```
1@gmail.com
1@gmail.com-1
1@gmail.com-2
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant snippet of code responsible for this for us to look at?

Comment: Share your registration code there are list of hooks that will help you once you share the code.

Comment: i dont writh nothing, only install this plugin : https://he.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-registration-forms/

Comment: this replace the defualt wordpress registration

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wp_insert_user` function to create a user without an email address.

```
$user_data = array(
  'user_login' => 'username-here',
  'user_pass'  => 'password-here',
);

$user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );

if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    // There was an error
} else {
    // Success!
}
```

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user

If you don't want to use a username you can generate a random one using `uniqid` php function.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php
Library: https://github.com/ramsey/uuid

Alternative you can use this helper function.

```
function uuid() {
    return sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
        mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
        mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
        mt_rand(0, 0x0fff) | 0x4000,
        mt_rand(0, 0x3fff) | 0x8000,
        mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff)
    );
}
```

See: https://solvit.io/50064cf

### Update - Unique user id after registration using easy registration forms

```
function uuid() {
  return sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
      mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
      mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
      mt_rand(0, 0x0fff) | 0x4000,
      mt_rand(0, 0x3fff) | 0x8000,
      mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff)
  );
}

add_action('erf_user_created', 'generate_unique_id_after_user_created', 10, 3);

function generate_unique_id_after_user_created( $user_id, $form_id,$sub_id ) {
  if( !empty( $user_id ) ) {
    $user_data = array(
      'ID' => $user_id,
      'user_login' => uuid(),
      'user_email' => '',
    );

    $updated_user_id = wp_update_user( $user_data );

    if ( is_wp_error( $updated_user_id ) ) {
      // There was an error, probably that user doesn't exist.
    } else {
      // Success!
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks ! iam sory about the quation, i past this code on Fuction.php ?

Comment: You will need to use it when you are creating a user. If you paste it in `functions.php` it will generate a new user every-time there is a request made on your website.

Comment: You can paste the `uuid` helper function somewhere in the file before you use it.

Comment: i want do it for new user every-time then user register on my website. iam dont know wher past your code, sory.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can try paste that one in your `functions.php` file.

Comment: tanks alot ! i past it in Function.php but when i register with same email its show me "This user is already taken״

Comment: Can you try create an account with a random email and see if it changes to a random string after the account is created?

Comment: i try with random email and its dont change after account is created. =\